# Any pointers to installing 12.04 on a single core dual xeon processor server (32 bit) with a new hard drive

Tags: 12.04, installation, server

I was given an older 32 bit single core dual xeon processor server. I'm hoping to make a file server out of it. it has 5 new 320Gb SCSI HD drives and 12Gb ddr266 ecc reg memory on an intel SE7501HG2 mother board. I've never installed ubuntu linux or any kind of linux before. So saying I'm green would be an understatement. and there is no way I'm shelling out $600.00 or more for a windows os. So Ubuntu it for me... if I can just figure out where to start...

Comment: Sorry, but your question is a bit vague; exactly what do you want help with?  Ubuntu installs well (not to mention easily) on most computers the majority of the time, so do you want help getting it configured as a file server or something similar?  Don't post an answer as a response to this comment, just edit your question.

Comment: Please specify what you want to do with the server. What features are essential for you, which are optional but nice to have. There are to much possible scenarios for an ubuntu server, you need to specify your scenario before the community could be of any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Niiice box.

Step 1. Go into BIOS and set up RAID 0. If you don't have raid 0, follow this guide.
Guide: https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/advanced-installation.html

Step 2. You want to grab the Server ISO and burn it to a disk.
Link: http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04.3/ubuntu-12.04.3-server-i386.iso

Step 3. Insert the CD and boot from it. Follow the wizard.

Finally, you want a file server, right? So you install SAMBA!
There are many documentations on Google on how to do that. Just search "SAMBA ubuntu server 12.04"

Configure that, and you're good to go!
Welcome to the wonderful world of Ubuntu, friend!

Comment: Thanks for helping out a green horn everything went great! got it up and running and serving up files left and right! Way faster than the windows box we had doing it before!

Comment: @LarryCrouse Not a problem. Glad it works well!

Answer (score 0):

Use the minimal CD and only install what you need: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD

If you need it to communicate well with Windows clients you should select samba file server during install. Otherwise, it is heavily recommended to use NFS instead because it is the preferred *nix method of file transfers. You can access NFS on Windows, but it requires a bit of setup on Windows PCs.